# Extract value from mysql json string stored as varchar

Tags: mysql

Have a mysql column with json like strings stored as varchar:

```
{'@type': 'Organization', 'legalName': 'some company inc.'}
```

I tried to extract it using the following:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(columnname, "$.legalName")
FROM tablename
WHERE indexfield='specifics'
```

But all i get is 'NULL' as output and a warning message " Current selection does not contain a unique column."

Comment: dont use double quotes for strings in mysql, but rather 'quotes`

Comment: Your JSON is broken to begin with. But the error is caused by something else.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON string in the first place. JSON keys and values should be wrapped within double quotes.

Comment: Replace single quotes with double quotes.... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=966f2a5523efa81efded7742238502e9

Comment: i have 350000 rows in the table, if i have the change the quotes, what is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON has to have its names and values wrapped in DOUBLE QUOTES like this

```
{"@type": "Organization", "legalName": "some company inc."}
```

So

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"@type": "Organization", "legalName": "some company inc."}', "$.legalName") as xxx;
```

Works

```
"some company inc."
```

While your example has single quotes

```
{'@type': 'Organization', 'legalName': 'some company inc.'}
```

So

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT("{'@type': 'Organization', 'legalName': 'some company inc.'}", "$.legalName") as xxx;
```

Does not work!

So it looks like the JSON you stored was not real JSON

Comment: This is NOT my JSON ! it's an web-scrapped  extract from another site.  Helpful to know if there a way to extract the desired value?

Comment: Well as its not valid JSON, then you will have to write something to fix all the data already on the database. You will also need to change the code that stores this on the database and do the NearlyJSON to RealJSON conversion so that no more bad data is stored on the database

Comment: Hi, Actually **I didnt Downvote you Question**. I tried to answer it, the 2 are really incompatible

Comment: my folly , apologies :-) new to stackoverflow !

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers helped resolve. So what I did was exported the table to csv, loaded to google sheet ( after splitting it into manageable size) and than used 'text to column' to extract the value from the json-like string.

After that, imported the csv into a temp table, tested and brought back live.

Comment: @ErgestBasha example would have worked insitu on the database rather than an unload/reload, and was basically what i suggested in my comment i.e. find some way of correcting the strings to make then valid JSON!